# Favorite an issue in GitHub

Tags: github, issue-tracking

Apologies if this is not enough of a coding question - please refer me to the right Stack Exchange platform if there is one more relevant for this question.

I had a problem with yarn / webpack with a create-react-app and I was not the first one - the issue has been reproduced and discussed before on [GitHub](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1164).

Is there a way for me to favorite this issue, or, in any other way follow progress on this issue, while not getting in the way of the discussion (since it seems they covered everything I was struggling with already)?

Comment: You should "watch" the issue

Comment: Great, thanks donkopotamus!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149784/favorite-an-issue-in-github#comment75317197_44149784) which suggests *kind of* the right solution.
 But the feature actually has a different name on GitHub, and I think calling it "watch" is confusing for people who aren't that familiar with GitHub's UI.
*(there's a big "Watch" button on the top of the issue, but it's on top of **all** pages of the repo, and it's for watching the whole repo, **not** this particular issue!)*

---

It's actually called **Notifications**, and it's down on the issue's right sidebar:

[image: "subscribe" button]

After clicking it, it shows that you are now "following" this issue:

[image: "unsubscribe" button]

Comment: There's now a feature that allows you to favorite an issue, which puts it in your own fav list in your profile. Handy, when you follow many issues, as they'll stand out more. However, I only see the button _after_ you subscribe and then only when you click a notification (I guess the feature is new and needs some ironing out).